# How to print properties of generic objects

Tags: c#, generics

I am a C# beginner and trying a new piece of code out. The following code doesn't print the values correctly:

```
namespace systemTypes
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
             CommonData<string>name = new CommonData<string>();
             name.Value = "abcd";
             CommonData<float>version = new CommonData<float>();
             version.Value = 2.0F;
             Console.WriteLine(
                 "generic object storing string val : {0}",
                 name.Value);
             Console.WriteLine(
                 "generic object storing float val : {0}",
                 version.Value);
         }
    }

    public class CommonData<T>
    {
        private T _data;
        public T Value
        {
            get
            {
                return this._data;
            }
            set
            {
                this._data = value;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

It prints blank for string value and zero for int value to the console. Do I need implement a default constructor? What am I missing here?

Comment: I can see one issue you may have: `CommonData<int> version = new CommonData<float>();`

Comment: `CommonData<int>version = new CommonData<float>();` <-- That won't compile.

Comment: How is a code that does not compile supposed to print values! It won't even start.

Comment: i agree , its a typing mistake, i assure that it is an float data type . now, i say, using this code displays a blank for string , and zero for float value.

Answer (score 2):

The compiler would have told you this was wrong:

```
CommonData<int>version = new CommonData<float>();
```

for which the compiler says:

> Error 1   Cannot implicitly convert type 'systemTypes.CommonData' to 'systemTypes.CommonData' some.cs 10  39  someproject

At the moment it **doesn't compile**, so you are running some old version that presumably had hard-coded zero. You aren't running the code you have shown.

*Working* code would have been:

```
CommonData<float>version = new CommonData<float>();
```

However, there are times when saying **too much** is asking for trouble; `var` would have worked fine first time:

```
var name = new CommonData<string>();
name.Value = "abcd";
var version = new CommonData<float>();
version.Value = 2.0F;
Console.WriteLine("generic object storing string val : {0}", name.Value);
Console.WriteLine("generic object storing float val : {0}", version.Value);
```

Here, `var` just means "compiler: you can see what is on the right - you figure out the variable type for me please". It doesn't mean "variant" or "dynamic" or anything like that.

Answer (score 1):

Because you have a compilation error at this line:

```
CommonData<int>version = new CommonData<float>();
```

Specifically:

> error CS0029: Cannot implicitly convert type `Test.CommonData<float>` to `Test.CommonData<int>`
>
> error CS0031: Constant value `2` cannot be converted to a `int`

You may be running an older binary. Fix the compilation error and see if you're problem doesn't go away.

To fix it:

1. Make sure your type arguments match. Pick either `int` or `float`. Or declare the variable with the `var` keyword on the left-hand side: `var version = new CommonData<float>();`
2. Assign a literal matching the type you picked in step 1 to the `Value` property. If you picked `int`, use `2`. If you picked `float`, use `2.0f`.

Answer (score 1):

This is a compile time error. You are declaring the generic type of `'int'` but instantiating with `'float'`
Corrected line is

```
CommonData<float> version = new CommonData<float>();
```